# Why is && at a higher precedence than || (Java)

Tags: java, operator-precedence

```
    boolean a = true;
    boolean b = true;
    boolean c = false;

    System.out.println(a || b && c); // true
    System.out.println(b && c || a); // true
```

I just recently discovered what I thought was a bit of an oddity here.  Why is it that `&&` and `||` are at different precedence levels?  I would have assumed that they were at the same level.  The above demonstrates it. both statements are true even though a left to right evaluation would give false for the first and true for the second.

Does anyone know the reasoning behind this?

(BTW, I would have just used a load of parentheses here, but it was old code which brought up the question)

Comment: Side note: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/ :)

Comment: Note: For infos, you can find here the table of operators' precedence in Java : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because in conventional mathematical notation, `and` ([logical conjunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction)) has higher precedence than `or` ([logical disjunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction)).

All non-esoteric programming languages will reflect existing convention for this sort of thing, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Gotcha. It was just something that I've never ran into until today.  I had a coworker ask me "which has a higher precedence".

Answer (score 13):

`&&` is the boolean analogue of multiplication (`x && y == x * y`), while `||` is the boolean analogue of addition (`x || y == (bool)(x + y)`). Since multiplication has a higher precedence than addition, the same convention is used.

Note that the most common "canonical" form for boolean expression is a bunch of or-ed together and-clauses, so this dovetails well with that.

Comment: Note that there are *two* [canonical normal forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form); sum-of-products and product-of-sums.

Comment: Hence the "most common" specifier. (Though I suppose that probably depends on sub-discipline.)

Comment: Now that you mention it, I have seen this in my EE classes.  Thanks, makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

That is the customary order of precedence for such operators. Other languages, such as C++ also have the same precedence order. The same holds for mathematical notation, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective#Order_of_precedence).